# Get image Title and ALT to show up in Gallery

Tags: jquery, image, title, image-gallery, alt

I have a code that takes the image ALT and displays it as image caption when the image is viewed as a slideshow. BUT this same code replaces the image Title that shows up on hover in Gallery view. I do understand somewhat the code below, but dont know how to make the ALT to function as it does, and to preserve Title showing up on hover WITHOUT image Titles getting replaced with their ALTs.
Here's the code I use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".gallery img").each(function(){
        var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
        $(this).parent().attr("title",function(i,val){
            return val == alt ? "" : alt;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This part of code:

```
$(this).parent().attr("title",function(i,val){
    return val == alt ? "" : alt;
});
```

Sets the title the way you don't want by checking if `alt` from `image` is equal `title` from the `parent` of the image, which must be an `a` tag so technically it does not have to do with the caption being shown that must be taken by your plugin when the `alt` is set, so basically this part of code is just on the way, remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Removing this segment got rid of the captions, and replaced them all (including Titles) with the generic "Gallery" text that I wanted to get of in the first place.

Comment: I'm afraid your gallery plugin was implemented in a "non-orthodox" way to need us to write this to fix it, by the looks `alt` and `title` are tied and won't be a quick workaround that will fix, what is the plugin and have you tried alternatives?

Comment: No idea what's going on. The Lightbox Plus Colorbox Wordpress plugin is as standard as it gets and Im using it on all the sites i build. This is the first time Im dealing with such a case. The plughin sofar has always behaved properly... but not this time. Im using the Karma theme, one of the most popular ones on Themeforest, and it's been updated regularly. From that standpoint Im thinking there's very little that hasn't been tweaked. Both are old products. Weird stuff this Title/Alt thing.